# How to pass arrays in ZF2 routes?

Tags: zend-framework2

for example, I want to get this url string

```
/1/2/3/4
```

In view:

```
$this->url('routeName', array(
    'a' => array(1, 2, 3, 4)
));
```

In controller:

```
print_r($this->params()->fromRoute('a'));
```

Output is:

```
array(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 4
);
```

Is it possible to create this route?

Comment: Yes, It is possible. You need to change in modul.config.php

Comment: I have tried this, but there are many errors triggered after I generate url with arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF it would work at all, it'd be using the class [`Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\WildCard`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Wildcard.php). Since I never got that one to be working the way i expected it to be though, i suggest you go the ZF2 way where you have full control over what you're doing ;) Parameters and configuration stuff should be named always! I suggest you create a simple route of type [`Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/Segment.php):

```
'routename' => array(
    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/:val1/:val2/:val3/:val4',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'controllername',
            'action'     => 'actionname'
        ),
        'constraints' => array(
            'val1' => '[0-9]+',
            'val2' => '[0-9]+',
            'val3' => '[0-9]+',
            'val4' => '[0-9]+'
        )
    )
)
```

If the requirements are different, obviously the route configuration would change. You'd need to set up the route like this:

```
$this->url('routename', array(
    'val1' => 1,
    'val2' => 2,
    'val3' => 3,
    'val4' => 4
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the url routing in module.config.php file like this:

```
'routename' => array(
    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => 'routename[/:val1][/:val2][/:val3][/:val4]',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'controllername',
            'action'     => 'actionname'
        ),
        'constraints' => array(
            'val1' => '[0-9]+',
            'val2' => '[0-9]+',
            'val3' => '[0-9]+',
            'val4' => '[0-9]+'
        )
    )
)
```

And then add the number by following this:

```
$this->url('routename', array(
    'val1' => 1,
    'val2' => 2,
    'val3' => 3,
    'val4' => 4
));
```

And you can get all the parameter by :

```
print_r($this->params());
```